# Simplify binomial coefficients sum

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Exercise requires to simplify this sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{20} \binom{50}{k}\binom{50}{20-k}$$

Tried to figure this out with no success.
I have only final answer, which is $\binom{100}{20}$.

Please help me figure out the logic behind this simplification.
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to choose $20$ out of $100$ you have to choose $k$ from the first $50$ and $20-k$ from the second $50$.

Comment: @lulu Actually, you have given a perfect answer. In my opinion you should post it as an answer before something else post one based on your comment.

Comment: @mfl Or... we can vote to close as an identical duplicate of the *exact same question* which appeared earlier this weekend and probably several times already over the past few years.

Comment: @mfl  I was writing it up as an answer when the duplicate got spotted.  As it is, I'll just leave it as a comment.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @JMoravitz I didn't realize that it was a duplicate question. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @JMoravitz I didn't realize it either. Odd, no?  This could hardly be a contest problem.

Comment: hmm sorry for that dupe... I tried to search but i guess i dont know how to search with mathematical notations :\ thanks everyone!

Comment: @Rom: It  is hard to search. By now, most questions are essentially duplicates.